# MongoTemplate criteria query translation seems incorrect

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm querying a collection that has a nested object.  The domain model looks like this:

```
@Document(collection="a")
public class A {

   protected Map<String, B> fields;
   protected String uuid;
   protected Date updatedTs;

   //Getters and setters and other fields omitted
}

public class B{

   protected String c;
   protected String d;

}
```

I'm querying using a criteria that looks like this:

```
{ "uuid" : "9DA291A4-1BAB-4B9C-844D-681C3F1ABF6E"}
```

which I create using

```
Criteria.where("uuid").is(uuid);
```

I can see that the criteria object doesn't contain other stuff, because I can print it out like this:

```
log.debug("Criteria: " + SerializationUtils.serializeToJsonSafely(c.getCriteriaObject()));
```

If I turn on debug logging for package org.springframework.data.mongodb.core, I can see that the query actually being sent to the server is:

```
{ "uuid" : "9DA291A4-1BAB-4B9C-844D-681C3F1ABF6E"} fields: null
```

Edit: My document contains a field called 'fields', and it seems that something in my code or in mongoTemplate / spring-data is actually searching for fields: null.  The log line from MongoTemplate confused me because fields: null is actually referring to a set of field names to return.

So, how can I search for documents matching that uuid without spring-data only returning documents where the property "fields" is null?

Meanwhile, still investigating how to get round this, because I can't change the document structure...

Comment: Your query will only return documents in class A since only class A has UUID field.  Fields:null means something else all together.  I see this all the time with debug mode on.  Most likely you only queried for a particular UUID and fields happened to be null.

Comment: It might be that I have my mapping wrong, but I'm not sure.  My documents are structured like this: {uuid: "abc123", fields: {"a":b","c":{"d":true}}}.  That's what I mean by nested document.  I don't know of any other way to map this sensibly other than as I have done.  I'm aware that the query will only return documents from  collection 'A'

Comment: why not try to query for {fields.a:"b"} and see if it works?

Comment: Hmm.  If I query with no criteria, I get all the documents in the collection, with all the nested documents.  If I query for a given uuid and some field value, I get all docs with that field value regardless of the uuid. It's like it's ignoring that part of the criteria.

Comment: Actually, scrap that last - I get all docs with no criteria, as expected, but if I add in a query for nodes containing a known nested object (which returns over 400 documents when run in the mongo shell),  then I get no results

Comment: can you post your query for nested object?

Comment: Sure - here's one: db.collection.find( { "entityId" : "B73B5EAA-3C14-4860-9B8A-3EB43F596B45" , "fields.Title" : { "$exists" : true}}); - This is what is printed in the mongoTemplate logs - returns no docs, but if run from the shell, it does.  I'm currently trying to determine if there is a problem with mapping of the nested doc somehow, but I don't think so, since I get the data if I query with no criteria at all

Comment: OK, getting there now - this immediate problem was due to an erroneous Converter

Comment: OK, the issue was a data issue that I compounded.  There was a document containing no entityId field.  Somehow, the default type conversion was trying to cast a string to an integer during conversion of that node.  A converter that I'd added to try to be lenient with conversion was somehow causing the criteria searches to fail.  I guess that I need to find out more about the inner workings of the conversion process and how it's used in spring-data. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The `fields` you see in the log output has nothing to do with your domain object. This is indicated by it being placed *outside* the JSON string. `fields` in this case is referring to the fields that shall be returned for each document found which essentially is a [projection mechanism.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#projection)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I figured that - it just threw me temporarily since it had the same name as one of my document properties.  I saw what it was logging when I looked in the source code for MongoTemplate